# Set visibility view in DialogFragment at runtime

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to update a DialogFragment display at runtime, setting the visibility of a view to VISIBLE or GONE depending on some conditions.

Basically, I inflate my layout in the DialogFragment, show a progress bar while I do some background request, and update the DialogFragment layout depending of the result of my request.

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't update my UI accordingly, even if the logs show that the method is invoked and the thread is the Main thread.
Any idea why ?

#### In DialogFragment

```
@Override
public void showData(List<MyDataViewModel> data) {
    Timber.d("Fragment Show data " + (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()));
    Timber.d("Fragment Show data " + this);
    Timber.d("Fragment Show data " + data.size());

    if (mConnectedContainer.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
        mConnectedContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

#### In Activity

```
@Override
public void showDialog() {
    // DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
    // in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
    // dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    // Create and show the dialog.
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
    newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
}
```

Also tried this way

```
@Override
public void showDialog() {
    // Create and show the dialog.
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, the issue was linked to my use of RxJava.
I was executing a first UseCase, and in the onNext, executing another one.

I split my code in two different dialogs to make it simpler, and have only one use case updating the UI, and no more issue.